# th colspan fails w3c validations

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

what is wrong with the following?

```
 <table>
 <tr> <th> Blah </th> <th colspan="2"> Something </th> </tr>
 <tr> <td> .. </td> <td colspan="2"> ... </td>  </tr>
 </table>
```

It says **Table column 3established by element th has no cells beginning in it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've validated your HTML code with two doctypes:

- HTML5;
- XHTML 1.0 Strict.

And your document was successfully checked as valid. 
You should try to revalidate it.

Comment: actually I made a typo above, corrected. You were right, previous was passing. I updated the code above. Anyway, I dont know why it still does not work, but it turned out that I do not even need colspan.

Comment: No, the code as posted, prefixed with just `<!doctype html></title></title>` does *not* validate at http://validator.w3.org

Comment: When you begin a new HTML5 webpage, you have to write the minimalist HTML code which is the following :                        <!doctype html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, there is no cell that begins in the third column. It thus violates the HTML table model as defined in HTML5, rather technically in [4.9.12 Processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#processing-model-1). Basically, the point is that you cannot create a column that consists *only* of slots created by cells starting in earlier columns and extending to other columns with `colspan`.

When using earlier versions of HTML, the error won’t be caught, since for them, validation is DTD-driven, and a DTD (document type definition, a formalized set of syntax rules written in SGML or XML) can only describe relatively simple syntax rules.

The most common cause of this problem seems to be a misguided idea of just making cells wider by using `colspan`. Instead, use the `width` attribute or, usually more preferably, the `width` property in CSS.